# Compiled ECMAScript 6 Everything is undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm new to ECMAScript and I'm facing weird issues. This is my directory tree:

```
js/
js/common/BaseObject.js
js/main.js
```

BaseObject.js:

```
export default class BaseObject {
  constructor() {
   console.log('init');
  }
}
```

main.js

```
import BaseObject from './common/BaseObject'
var Foo = new BaseObject();
```

Everything is compiled through webpack and babel-loader.

When I try to run the browser page it gives no error, loads the script page correctly but Foo and BaseObject are undefined. I guess it's something stupid but I can't really figure out.

Comment: *"it gives no error"* and *"Foo and BaseObject are undefined"* are completely at odds. Do you get the `"init"` string in your console from the constructor?

Comment: If webpack is minifying your code, your symbol names have probably been re-defined as shorter versions of their former selves

Comment: @Phil thank you for the edit. Yes I get the init string.

**Edit:** No, the code hasn't been modified, just concatenated.

Comment: Doesn't sound like you've got a problem then

Comment: The code isn't changed by webpack at all but everything written in main.js runs perfectly. If I try to access to "Foo" from the browser console it gives me undefined :\ any idea?

Comment: The code in `main.js` is probably run in an IIFE so the variables defined there are not in the global scope

Comment: @zangarmarsh module scopes are private scopes. If you want your variables to get exported in the global scope, you'd need to tell webpack.

Comment: Oh ok guys thank you so much.